# Theorem 5.9 Rudin's Real and Complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm trying to understand the proof the of the following theorem:

> **The Open Mapping Theorem** Let $U, V$ be the unit open balls of the Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$. To every bounded linear transformation $\Lambda$ of $X$ onto $Y$ there's a $\delta > 0$ such that
>   $$
> \delta V \subset \Lambda (U)
> $$

I report the proof, with my questions.

> Proof : Given $y \in Y$ there's an $x \in X$ such that $\Lambda x = y$;

This clearly follows from the *onto* of the statement of the theorem, right?

> if $\left\lVert x \right\rVert < k$, it follows that $y \in \Lambda(kU)$. Hence $Y$ is the union of the sets $\Lambda(kU)$, for $k = 1,2,3 ...$. Since $Y$ is complete, the Baire Theorem implies that there's a non empty open set $W$ in the closure of some $\Lambda(kU)$.

I believe Baire theorem is applied as follows:
Since a complete metric space is not of first category it means *it cannot* be a countable union of nowhere dense, implying that there's $k$ such that $\Lambda(kU)$ *is not* a nowhere dense, which implies that for such $k$ there's a non empty openset $W \subseteq \bar{\Lambda}(kU)$. Is it correct?

> This means that every point of $W$ is the limit of a sequence $\left\{ \Lambda x_i \right\}$, $x_i \in kU$. From now on, $k$ and $W$ are fixed.
>   Chose $y_0 \in W$, and choose $\eta > 0$, so that $y + y_0 \in W$ if $\left\lVert y \right\rVert < \eta$. For such $y$ there're sequences $\left\{ x_i' \right\}, \left\{ x_i'' \right\}$ such that
>   $$
> \Lambda x_i' \to y_0, \;\;\; \Lambda x_i'' = y_0 + y \;\;\;, i \to \infty
> $$
>   Setting $x_i = x_i'' - x_i'$, we have $\left\lVert x_i \right\rVert < 2k$ and $\Lambda x_i \to y$. Since this hold for every $y$ with $\left\lVert y \right\rVert < \eta$, the linearity of $\Lambda$ shows that the following is true if $\delta = \eta/2k$
>
> *To each $y \in Y$ and to each $\epsilon > 0$ there's an $x \in X$ such that*
>   $$
> \left\lVert x \right\rVert < \delta^{-1}\left\lVert y \right\rVert \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; \left\lVert y - \Lambda x \right\rVert < \epsilon \;\;\; (3)
> $$

I can't really figure how this bit follows from the linearity and our assumption on $\delta$, can you clarify?

I can't also quite figure what's the purpose of the final part of the proof

> Fix $y \in \delta V$, and fix $\epsilon > 0$. By (3) there's an $x_1$ with $\left\lVert x_1 \right\rVert < 1$ and
>   $$
> \left\lVert y - \Lambda x \right\rVert < \frac{1}{2}\delta \epsilon
> $$

Why do we have $\left\lVert x_1 \right\rVert < 1$?

> Suppose $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are chosen so that
>   $$
> \left\lVert y - \Lambda x_1 - \ldots - \Lambda x_n \right\rVert < 2^{-n}\delta \epsilon \;\;\; (5)
> $$
>   Use (3), with $y$ replaced by the vector on the left side of (5), to obtain an $x_{n+1}$ so that (5) holds with $n+1$ in place of $n$, and
>   $$
> \left\lVert x_{n+1} \right\rVert < 2^{-n}\epsilon
> $$

I think all the rest will be clear once someone sheds some lights on my questions.

Comment: This reminded me that we spent some time in chat both with [open mapping theorem](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19167/conversation/theorem-2-11-from-rudin-open-mapping-theorem) and [Banach Steinhaus theorem](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19167/conversation/theorem-2-5-from-rudin-banach-steinhaus-for-tvs).

Comment: I think that discussion was related to the versions given by "Functional Analysis", but yeah is a similar discussion. I was looking for applications, and I saw a few related to fourier series are given in "Real and Complex analysis". But the proof of the theorem is slightly different.

Comment: I have noticed this among related questions in the sidebar: [Problem in proof of open mapping theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1989950) It seems to be about one part of your question. (Probably the most relevant one.)

Comment: I read through that, but the thing is the vector $y$ is normalized to a one of norm exactly $\eta$, but if $\left\lVert y \right\rVert < \eta$ then $\left\lVert x \right\rVert < 2k$, this is where I'm struggling (among the things). If $\left\lVert y \right\rVert = \eta$ I don't think I can imply the same thing.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Is there any chance we can have a chat about a problem I'm having in an exercise? I really can't figure how to solve it. I've asked a question already.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems with your application of surjectivity and also with the application of Baire category theorem the way you described it.

> I can't really figure how this bit follows from the linearity and our assumption on $\delta$, can you clarify?$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}$

Maybe I am missing something, but I am only able to show this if we assume $\norm y\le\eta$. (Still, it is true that there exists $\eta>0$ such that closed $\eta$-ball around $y_0$ is inside $W$.) EDIT: However, see [Daniel Fischer's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468467/theorem-5-9-rudins-real-and-complex-analysis/3469633#comment7133110_3469633) for a way to do this with strict inequality.

I.e., I will try to work as if this part of the proof says: "choose $\eta > 0$, so that $y + y_0 \in W$ if $\norm{y}\le\eta$".

Now, suppose we are given arbitrary $y\in Y$. Let us denote
$$\widetilde y=\frac{\eta}{\norm{y}}y.$$
Since $\norm{\widetilde y}=\eta$, we have that there exists a sequence of points $x_i$ such that $\norm{x_i}<2k$ and $\Lambda x_i\to \widetilde y$. In particular, we can choose $\widetilde x$ such that $\norm{\widetilde y-\Lambda\widetilde x}<\frac\eta{\norm y} \varepsilon$.

Now if we denote $C=\frac{\norm y}\eta$ and take
$$x=C \widetilde x$$
then we have 
$$\norm{y-\Lambda x} = \norm{C(\widetilde y-\Lambda\widetilde x)}= C\norm{\widetilde y-\Lambda\widetilde x}<\varepsilon.$$
At the same time
$$\norm x=C\norm{\widetilde x}<\frac1\delta\cdot C\norm{\widetilde y}=\frac1\delta\norm{y}.$$

> Why do we have $\left\lVert x_1 \right\rVert < 1$?

If we are using $(3)$ for $y\in\delta V$, that means that $\norm y<\delta$ then we have
$$\norm{x}\le \frac1\delta\norm{y} < 1.$$

Comment: It's of course easier to work with non-strict inequalities, but we can get the result as stated. With $\tilde{y} = \frac{\eta}{\lVert y\rVert} y$ (for $y \neq 0$, the case $y = 0$ is trivial) set $$\hat{y} = \biggl(1 - \frac{\min\{\varepsilon, \lVert y\rVert\}}{2\lVert y\rVert}\biggr)\tilde{y}\,.$$ Then $\lVert \hat{y}\rVert < \eta$, $\lVert \hat{y} - \tilde{y}\rVert \leqslant \frac{\eta}{2\lVert y\rVert}\varepsilon$. Pick $\tilde{x}$ with $\lVert \tilde{x}\rVert < 2k$ and $\lVert \hat{y} - \Lambda\tilde{x}\rVert < \frac{\eta}{2\lVert y\rVert}\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak, sorry but in your answer if $\left\lVert \tilde{y} \right\rVert = \eta$ how does it follow that $\left\lVert x_i \right\rVert < 2k$? This would be true if $\left\lVert \tilde{y} \right\rVert < \eta$, but in case of equality I don't see how it follows.

Comment: @user8469759 As I have mentioned in the post, I am working with a modification of the original proof. (In this part: I.e., I will try to work as if this part of the proof says: "choose $\eta > 0$, so that $y + y_0 \in W$ if $\|y\|\le\eta$.)

Comment: Let me read the section again from the book, because I think there might be a mistake.